# How can we check if location and google search is enabled in android device with OS 4.1?

Tags: location

Location and Google location search is a setting in android devices with android 4.1 devices.

There is obviously an efficient way to check if GPS and NETWORK is enabled but how do we check if the third option ie. Location and Google location search in the location settings is enabled?

Comment: If GPS or NETWORK are turned on then the third option must be on. If you turn the third option off, it turns off GPS and NETWROK on my phone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its true what you say, but this happens in case of the OS version 4.2 and above. In case the OS version is 4.1, there are three independent options, 1)Use Wirless networks 2) Use GPs 3) Location and Google search which can be checked or unchecked. I need a way to check if the third option is enabled

Comment: Ah ok sorry I'm running 4.2.2